# Using a file as a database?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

From Entity Framework using ASP .NET MVC 3.0, is it possible to use a file as a database while testing? I am aware of the speed of such operations.

In my scenario, I just don't want a database to run all the time on my computer. Neither do I want to start it up when I need to.

Is it possible? I'm not looking for MDF files. I'm looking for ways to save entire data on the disk.

Comment: Have a look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: So you want to use a file as a database but don't want to use MDF files?  It seems like SQL Server Express being mounted to MDF files would be exactly what you need.  This is what I've done in the past for automated unit testing / local development and it worked great.

Comment: Sadly he does not want the db server to start dyynamically either.

Comment: Is it feasible to stick all the database access behind a Repository interface?  You could then swap in a testing implementation that reads from a file (or just had hardcoded results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to use a file as a database while testing?

Yes, it is. All you need to do is to define a database format for the file, write the handlers, write all teh logic infvolved and then write a provider for Entity Framework to use, including tooling support for visual studio.

All in all a couple of man years of work.

So yes, it is POSSIBLE, but it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

How about SQL Server Compact Edition, performance isn't too bad and it works similar to SQLite but has all the .Net bindings in and they are really similar to the System.Data.SQLClient commands.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494.aspx